# When using HttpWebRequest on WP7, Request.EndGetResponse throwing "Not Found" error after 1 minute

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am using HttpWebRequest to call a webservice from WP7.

Everything works fine on WP7 emulator but when i use WP7 device, it throws "Not Found" exception if webservice doesn't respond in 1 minute.

i did not find any property to increase the timeout of HttpWebRequest in WP7 framework.

below is code i am using

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            var res = request.BeginGetRequestStream(
               new AsyncCallback((streamResult) =>
               {

                   byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapRequestEnvelope);

                   try
                   {
                       using (Stream requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(streamResult))
                       {
                           requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(soapRequestEnvelope));
                       }
                   }
                   catch (Exception e)
                   {

                   }

                   request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((ar) =>
                   {
                       try
                       {

                           HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
                           if (Request != null)
                           {
                               //below line throws error if response doesn't come in 1 Minute

                               using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)Request.EndGetResponse(ar))
                               {
                                  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

                                  //Response comes here
                                  string text =  reader.ReadToEnd();
                               }
                           }
                       }
                       catch (Exception ex)
                       {
                       }

                   }), request);

               }), request);
```

Pleae help me out?

Thanks,
SK

Comment: Do you know what type of response you are receiving from the web server? I'm most interested in the http status code, i.e. 200[OK], 304[NOT MODIFIED] etc. Also is the webservice responding immediately?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Or have you found the statuscode returned? We can't help you further if you don't reply

Comment: Sadly, NotFound does not mean anything, it is the generic error and you have to dig deeper to find out what the real error is.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you're not calling a local web service, your device is not able to resolve localhost instead of emulator